# Abnormal termination of GNU Octave script

Tags: bash, octave, exit

On a i686 / 32-bit dual CPU, with a fresh Debian Stretch installation, I've installed Octave 4.2.1 and run `./mytest` after providing it with execution privileges:

```
#!/bin/bash
./mytest.m
```

where `test.m` reads

```
#!/usr/bin/octave
exit(0)
```

The result is:

```
Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'octave::exit_exception'
panic: Aborted -- stopping myself...
attempting to save variables to 'octave-workspace'..
save to 'octave-workspace' complete
octave exited with signal 6
```

but the program is intended to exit normally. Same result replacing `exit` with `quit`, but it terminates correctly when starting it with `$ octave -q --no-gui` and then `> quit`. What's wrong here?

Update: In the meanwhile, this showed up: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?49271, so now the question would be: can a non-Octave configuration solve the problem? (Confirmed: Octave 4.0.0 does not reproduce the error.)

Comment: Let's try starting it without bash at all -- if the issue still reproduces, we can remove the shell from the question entirely: `python -c 'import subprocess; subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/octave", "test.m"])'`

Comment: If that *doesn't* reproduce the exception, I'd want to see output from `bash -x ./mytest`, having the shell log exactly what it's running -- presumably, in that case, we have some hidden characters in the shell script which Octave doesn't agree with.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy all combinations end up with the same result, with or without bash or python/bash call. In the meanwhile, this showed up: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?49271

Comment: "from a bash shell" can presumably be removed from the question, then. But -- looks like you've found your root cause.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy agreed, and done. Thx!

Comment: @nightcod3r what is your point here? What do you want to solve and why do you have "exit" in your code? If you call your script via bash the interpreter stops if the end of your script is reached, no need for `exit`

Comment: @Andy sometimes you need to make clear that the program has exited correctly. This is just a toy example, but the error raised in a more elaborated Octave script that is launched every time it stops by pressing Ctrl-C, so user-driven abnormal termination is an option, but the bash script which is calling can't sort out this situation from the abnormal exit described in this question.

Comment: And you don't want to install default where it is fixed since more than 6 months? If it's so important for you to use 4.2.x (and not 4.0.x) but you don't want to run the development version you can bisect the change which fixed this and add this to the bugtracker. Then port this patch to the stable tree and build. Hint: use hg bisect and your testscript

Comment: @Andy That's precisely what I would do, but this particular program will be used in an academic network, kept by a government admin crew, meaning that anything out of the official repositories is not welcome (or, in practice, won't be used at all).

Comment: which are "official repositories"?

Comment: @Andy for Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories, i.e such that you don't need third-party PPAs, and no additional testing is needed for compatibility.